# Can I specify that I only want the .sty file from a .dtx?

Tags: package-writing

I've been trying to be good and make my proto-packages `.dtx` files (in particular, the files in the [TeX-SX Package](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1220/86) but that's not particularly relevant).  My workflow goes a bit like this:

1. Hack a few macros with tests in a `.tex` file
2. Fork the macro bit into a `.sty` file and the tests stay in a `.tex` file
3. Munge the macros into something reasonable
4. Convert the tests into something approximating documentation
5. Convert the `.sty` file to a `.dtx`
6. Add the documentation
7. Announce it [somewhere](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/409/from-answers-to-packages) and ask for testers

At this point, I enter the "add feature and fix bugs" stage.  Editing the `.dtx` is a little less intuitive than the `.sty` (having to remember the `macrocode` stuff, but I'm getting used to it), but I don't usually want to rebuild the documentation every time - I usually have a separate test file that tests only those bits that I'm editing.  So whilst I'm okay at adding `pdflatex file.dtx` to generate the new `.sty` file, it's a bit much that it generates the documentation as well.  Not only is it a waste of *time* but also can hide any errors in the `.sty` bit under a wreath of information about the documentation bit.

So: how do I tell `pdflatex` to *only* generate the `.sty` file when I run `pdflatex file.dtx`?

(Incidentally, if anyone happens to suggest any improvements on my workflow, I'll be very grateful.)

Comment: Hack, Fork, Munge... I think step 4 should be "splice the tests..." and 5. should be "whizz the `.sty`..."

Comment: @Seamus: Vær så godt!  (aka: feel free to edit accordingly!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach I use is to have a `.dtx` file structured such that `pdflatex <filename>.dtx` will extract the code *and* typeset the documentation, while `tex <filename>.dtx` will only do the extraction. The one I use is basically

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
%</readme>
Some README information here :-)
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
---------------------------------------------------------------
<PACKAGE> --- <DESCRIPTION>
Maintained by <NAME>
E-mail: <EMAIL>
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
---------------------------------------------------------------

\endpreamble
\postamble
Copyright (C) DATE by
  <NAME> <<EMAIL>>

It may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either version 1.3c of
this license or (at your option) any later version.  The latest
version of this license is in the file:
   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
  <NAME>.

This work consists of the file  <PACKAGE>.dtx
          and the derived files <PACKAGE>.pdf,
                                <PACKAGE>.sty and
                                <PACKAGE>.ins.

\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/<PACKAGE>}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/<PACKAGE>}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/<PACKAGE>}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc} % or whatever
%\DisableImplementation
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% 
% CODE AND DOCUMENTATION HERE
```

What happens is that the tests (inside the `internal` guards) mean that the extraction is done inside a group for LaTeX but is not for plain TeX, which instead exits before getting to the documentation part.

The way I then use this for testing is to have a very simple test file, with `\write18` enabled. Something like

```
\immediate\write18{tex <FILENAME>.dtx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{<FILENAME>}
\begin{document}
  Tests here.
\end{document}
```

which lets me do a lot of simple (or less simple) testing without needing to typeset everything.

Comment: On the basis that I copied my `.dtx` template from your blog, I tested this fully expecting it to work with no modification ... and it did!  Fantastic!  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: I suspected that from your other comments, but as answers are intended to be self-contained decided to post more-or-less the same stuff here. Also, in this particular case I've tried to focus on the one point in hand.

Answer (score 8):

You probably put the installer code into the `.dtx` file as well. This style seems to be some form of fashion nowadays. The classic way to do this as shown in the `clsguide` is to put the `docstrip` command into a separate `.ins` file which then extracts the `.sty` file:

So, unpack using:

```
pdflatex somepackage.ins   % extract .sty file
```

While:

```
pdflatex somepackage.dtx   % compile manual
```

I'm using Makefile's for all my packages and have a `unpack` target for the first line, so I only need to say `make unpack` or `make package` which is an alias.

---

A minimal example of a `.ins` file would be:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\generate{\file{somepackage.sty}{\from{somepackage.dtx}{package}}}
\endbatchfile
```

See the `clsguide` for a larger example.

Comment: I did put the installer in to the `.dtx`.  It was a bit of "Cargo Cult Programming" based on examples at Joseph's blog (which _you_ directed me to!).  I like having _absolutely_ everything in one file.  But while I'm writing the stuff then having a separate `.ins` is perfectly reasonable.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: You can have both, i.e. the install code twice internal and external. Then only use the `.ins` file if you want the `.sty` file only. There is some trickery with conditionals passed by the Makefile but I would try to avoid this.

Comment: That's what I tried and it worked fine (except that I had to name the external one something other than `package.ins` so that it didn't get overwritten if I inadvertently called `pdflatex` on the `.dtx`).

Comment: Sorry, Martin - Joseph's answer just happens to be the right answer _for my specific situation_ since I copied my `.dtx` template from his blog, so he gets the 'accepted'.  I hope you won't feel _too_ disappointed.